# How to Handle Action that does not need to change any state?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have built a React app that is being displayed at a museum exhibit. One specific part of the app contains a Survey Component, where various options can be voted on by the group currently viewing the exhibit. When the survey is submitted by the group, the vote counts are then used inside of a React graphing component I built.

***Initially***, this action sent out a post request with some data to a Mongo database. Once posted, it would combine that data with the last 30 days of results from the database, and use it inside of a React graphing component.

**Now,** the customer just wants the data from the current session to be displayed in the graph, so there is no longer a need to query the database for data to use inside the graph, I already have the data I need saved in the component level state.

However, I still need to save the vote results to the database for data analytics purposes. Seeing as in the exhibit viewers do not need to know about the data being saved to the database, I am not sure how to write my redux action, as there is no need to update any state within the application. If the data fails to save to the db, so be it, I do not want to notify the viewers of the app that anything failed.

So, temporarily, I decided to create a method inside of my React Component that performs the AJAX post to the database.

```
  saveSurveyResults = () => {
    const { options } = this.props
    const { voteCount } = this.state
    let newArr = []

    let i = 0
    let randomId = uuidv4()

    for(let x in voteCount) {
      if(voteCount[x] > 0) {
        newArr.push (
          {
            group_id: randomId,
            option_id: options[i].id,
            option_text: options[i].title,
            count: voteCount[x],
            timestamp: new Date().valueOf()
          }
        )
      }
      i++
    }

    if(newArr.length < 1)
      return this.setState({ error: true })

    axios.post(API_SAVE_SUBMISSION, {
      submissions: newArr
    })
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res.status)
    })
  }
```

Basically, this method ends with the AJAX request, and just assumes everything goes well, with no feedback to the user. I feel like this is hacky.

I'd like to keep all of my AJAX requests outside of my components, and have them all flow through Redux for ease of updating in the future, as I feel like its neater to do it this way.

I currently have a reducer for my Survey component that returns a new piece of state for one action, which is triggered when the group clicks the submit survey button.

```
import { SUBMIT_SURVEY } from '../actions/types'

export default function(state = {}, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case SUBMIT_SURVEY:
      return action.payload
  }
  return state
}
```

Here is the action that is emitted when the group clicks the button. It just sends a plain JavaScript object with the vote counts for each option to the reducer.

```
export function submitSurveyResults(votes) {
  return {
    type: SUBMIT_SURVEY,
    payload: votes
  }
}
```

Here is a simple custom middleware I am using that resolves AJAX requests for me. Might not be necessary to understand how it works, but here it is anyways. Just assume it resolves AJAX requests perfectly.

```
export default function({ dispatch }) {
  return next => action => {

    if(!action.payload || !action.payload.then)
      return next(action)

    action.payload
      .then(function(res) {
        const newAction = { ...action, payload: res }
        dispatch(newAction)
      })
  }
}
```

What is the best way to refactor my current method, and have it flow through Redux instead? I know this question may seem elementary, but hopefully someone with more skill will understand what I am trying to do.

Here is an example of another AJAX request I have inside an action, that works just fine.

```
export function getPersonQuestions(personId) {
  const questions = axios.get(`${getUrlFromBody()}ajax_questions?id=${personId}`)

  return {
    type: GET_QUESTIONS,
    payload: questions
  }
}
```

I guess I am just confused if I should just emit an action with an AJAX request similar to the one above, and then just have it return the current state in my reducer, without returning a new piece of state?

Comment: What are you using in redux for ajax requests?

Comment: I am using the npm module axios

Comment: Are you using a middleware of some kind, such redux-thunk or redux-saga?

Comment: Oh yeah, my bad. Give me a few mins. I will post the code for what I am using. Its a custom async handler. That will clear things up

Comment: I have updated the question. I think my question is really simple, but, I am just wondering if there is another way to go about things.

Comment: Your middleware gets the ajax call promise, and dispatches a new action. You can add a flag to the original action, that prevents dispatch.

Comment: As @OriDrori mentioned, I recommend orchestrating your async requests using Redux Saga. A great tutorial on using it is [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-media-library-with-react-redux-and-redux-saga-part-2#toc-step-5-of-8-define-async-task-handlers)

Comment: Very nice. Thanks guys. I will look into this.